# Problems with YAML If, elseif conditionals

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to use some conditional statements in one of our Azure Devops pipelines and I'm struggling to get the conditional to pass if the statement is set to true. I'm trying to do this so that we could specify which computer we would want to use for a task if one of them wasn't working, but to just pick one randomly from the pool if they were all good to go. Any ideas why these conditionals are not getting hit?

I've tried the inverse logic of not equals instead of equals and that seems to trigger the condition, but not the other way around. I've checked to make sure that the variable is getting set to true or false based off what I set it, and it seemed to work for other tasks. Any help would be appreciated

Here's the variables that are getting set

```
variables:
    - name: foo1
      # Here the azure variable 'variable1' would be set to 'true' and 'variable2 would be set to 'false'
      value: $(variable1)
    - name: foo2
      value: $(variable2)
```

Here's where the build is getting the demands

```
- job: build
    displayName: build
    timeoutInMinutes: 180
    pool:
      name: 'pool'
      ${{ if eq(variables.foo1, 'true') }}:
        demands:
          - Agent.ComputerName -equals computer1
      ${{ elseif eq(variables.foo2, 'true') }}:
        demands:
          - Agent.ComputerName -equals computer2
      ${{ else }}:
        demands:
          - otherdemands
```

Comment: `$()` is macro syntax and is evaluated at runtime. `${{}}` is compilation-time syntax and is evaluated at template compilation time, long before runtime variables are available. Use compilation-time syntax, `${{ variables.variable1 }}`.

Comment: Where are the variables `variable1` and `variable2` coming from?

Comment: Also what's the reason behind setting the value of one variable (`foo1`) with another another (`variable1`) ?

Comment: Variable1 & 2 are coming from the variables that you can set at the pipeline level. The reason I was using the foo variables to pass in the information was because I was getting syntax errors when I tried to reference variable1 or 2 directly

Comment: what was the syntax error? also pipeline variables might not be available at compile time which makes it difficult to use them in conditions, have you tried to using `parameters` instead?

Comment: Yep we got it working with parameters. Thanks